# Show that Every Group Is the Homomorphic Image of a Free Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The following was taken from Hungerford.  This is how the author constructed a set, $F$, of reduced words on an arbitrary set $X$.  Then, he proceeded to show that $F$ is a free group in the category of groups.

> Given a set $X$ we shall construct a group $F$ that is free on the set $X$ in the sense of Definition 7.7. If $X = \emptyset$, $F$ is the trivial group $\langle e \rangle$. If $X \neq \emptyset$ let $X^{-1}$ be a set disjoint from $X$ such that $|X| = |X^{-1}|$. Choose a bijection $X \to X^{-1}$ and denote the image of $x \in X$ by $x^{-1}$. Finally choose a set that is disjoint from $X \cup X^{-1}$ and has exactly one element; denote this element by $1$. A **word** on $X$ is a sequence $(a_1, a_2, \dotsc)$ with $a_i \in X \cup X^{-1} \cup \{1\}$ such that for some $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $a_k = 1$ for all $k \geq n$. The constant sequence $(1, 1, \dotsc)$ is called the **empty word** and is denoted by $1$. (This ambiguous notation will cause no confusion.) A word $(a_1, a_2, \dotsc)$ on $X$ is said to be **reduced** provided that
>
> 1. for all $x \in X$, $x$ and $x^{-1}$ are not adjacent (that is, $a_i = x \implies a_{i+1} \neq x^{-1}$ and $a_i = x^{-1} \implies a_{i+1} \neq x$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $x \in X$) and
> 2. $a_k = 1$ implies $a_i = 1$ for all $i \geq k$.
>
> In particular, the empty word is reduced.

To show that every group $G$ is the homomorphic image of a free group, we let $X$ be the generating set of $G$.  So, every element in $G$ takes the form $a_1^{c_1}a_2^{c_2} \ldots a_n^{c_n}$ where each $a_i \in X$.  Rewrite the element as $a_1a_2 \ldots a_s$ where $s = c_1 + c_2 \ldots + c_n$.  Is it possible to have $a_ia_k = 1$ for some $i, k$?  Based on the author's definition, the answer seems to be no.  With the bijection between $X$ and $X^{-1}$:
$$a_i \mapsto a_i^{-1} = a_k \text{ and } a_k \mapsto a_k^{-1} = a_i$$
This contradicts that $X \cap X^{-1} = \emptyset$.  Hence, if $a \in X$, you will not find its inverse in $X$ ....  Did I understand this correctly?

Now, forget that $X$ is the generating set of $G$.  What if I have a set $Y \subset G$ such that $1 \in Y$, or $a, a^{-1} \in Y$?  In that case, then I cannot construct $Y^{-1}$.  If $Y$ contains $1$, then $Y^{-1}$ also contains $1$.  If $Y$ contains $a, a^{-1}$, so does $Y^{-1}$.  Therefore, in the construction of $F$, the beginning set $Y$ is not arbitrary.  Specifically, $Y$ is devoid of inverses and $1$.

Comment: How does Definition 7.7 characterize the free group on a set $X$? Do you know the universal property of the free group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When constructing the free group on a set of generator, you should only see it as a set, and forget that it is also a subset of the group. So for example, the elements $x^{-1}$ obtained using some bijection $X\to X^{-1}$ as in your text are **not** the inverses of the elements of $X$, but rather new elements that need not even be in $G$. Similarly the element $1$ is **not** the unit of $G$, but again some new element not necessarily in $G$.

Your free group is constructed as explained in your text, and can be mapped onto $G$ by sending every element of $X$ to itself, every $x^{-1}$ to the inverse of $x$ in $G$, $1$ to the unit in $G$, and every word to the corresponding product, computed in $G$.

Comment: I agree that the elements in $X^{-1}$ do not have to be in $G$.  However, if $F$, the set of reduced words, is a group, then the element $y \in F$ such that $xy = 1_F = yx$ still has to be somewhere.  It may be inside $X^{-1}$, or it may be some combination of elements in both $X, X^{-1}$, but $y$ cannot be inside $X$, supporting my original contention that $X$ is not just arbitrary.

Comment: Maybe I am putting the cart before the horse.  Let say we begin with an arbitrary $X$, and then figure out $X^{-1}$ and $1_F$.  Only at this point, do we pair up $x \in X$ and $y \in X^{-1}$ such that $xy = 1_F = yx$.

Answer (score 1):

Given a group $G$, and its generating set $X$, it is usually *not* the case that $G$ is free over $X$, for example, if $g \in X \subset G$ has finite order, say, $n$, then the "words" $g^n = ggg\cdots g$ ($n$-fold product) and $1_G$ (represented by the "empty word") are distinct words in $F(X)$ but the same in $G$. This is why groups (in general) are merely homomorphic images of free groups, in a "typical" group, we have "non-trivial relations" (a word in a free group that gets mapped to the identity under a homomorphism $F(X) \to G$ is called a "relator"). In a finite cyclic group, which has one generator, the homomorphism in question (say for $X = \{x\}$) from $F(X) \to C_n$ has kernel the subgroup of $F(X)$ generated by the word $x^n = xx\cdots x$ ($n$ letters in word), and $x$ gets mapped to some generator of $C_n$ (say, $a$, for example).

This corresponds to the quotient $F(X)/\langle x^n\rangle$...since $F(X) \cong \Bbb Z$ (under addition), and the subgroup of $F(X)$ generated by $x^n$ is isomorphic to (under the same isomorphism) $n\Bbb Z$, then in this particular instance we have the usual:

$C_n \cong \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, which should not be surprising ($(\Bbb Z,+)$ *is* free over the set $\{1\}$-the freeness of the integers under addition captures what we *mean* by "different numbers (integers) are unequal").

The point being, unless our group $G$ is free over its generating set $X$ (and, for example, all finite groups are NOT), you should *expect* that there will be relations that hold in $G$, but not in $F(X)$; a homomorphism is *not* an isomorphism, in general.